# android overlay View without permission

Tags: android

I make an app for video chat but i faced the first issue and its when app receive   call a overlay an View for make user select accept call or refuse this work good in

> 4.4.2 kitkat

But when i test it in marshmallow its give me

> over draw detect

Error now when i use apps like viber and messenger i can't see any of this error and without give any permission for over draw  did they use an activity for thats ?
so if i use activity for make  a video chat when activity its paused will lose the call its must be in service with overlay view any idea ?

Comment: http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/07/android-m-begins-locking-down-floating-apps-requires-users-to-grant-special-permission-to-draw-on-other-apps/

Answer (score 0):

If you're targetting at least API 23 you must explicitly ask user to grant the permission, for apps below it draw overlay is enabled by default (but can still be manually revoked in settings).

There's also a quirky behavior (until Oreo) where system permission request will get blocked with Overlay Detected error if any overlay is attached (in API 26+ overlays are hidden automatically for duration of request).